# How do I actually install Docker on Windows 8.1? (Docker Toolbox for Windows 8.1 was deprecated recently)

Tags: docker

Edit: I would like to add that, attempting to install "docker windows" on windows 8.1 gave me an error informing me to upgrade to windows 10 but I really wish to stick to windows 8.1 hence my question. (just to clear any confusion)

So I was given this advice by someone else

"I you have a good computer, you can use VirtualBox and download the .iso file of a linux distribution and create your virtual machine. You have tutorials or VirtualBox guide (I have the complete steps in my course , but is write in french :sweat_smile: ) ... is my favorite solution because is fast and easly to deploy, but you must have a good computer ...
dualboot is more "professional" but he can be complicated to deploy the fist time and if you make a mistake, is not good ... and the last solution is virtual private server, but is not free "

But I find the above advice a little complicated for me at the moment as I'm not well-acquainted with it. So I would like to ask if there's actually another alternative to installing docker on windows 8.1? Can I even use docker on windows 8.1?

Comment: Like I've mentioned above, that does not work. "Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise (16299+) or Windows 10 Home (18362.1040+)."

Answer (score 4):

Just because its deprecated doesnt mean you cant use it. It just means that the Docker team is no longer developing it and therefore there wont be any new releases or updates.

If you cant upgrade to Windows 10 and installing Linux is not an option for you, the only thing you can do is use Docker Toolbox. Just get it from here and install it https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases/tag/v19.03.1